# Inserting different data simultaneously from different clients

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I created a windows forms application in C #, and a database `MS SQL server 2008 Express`, and I use `LINQ-to-SQL` query to insert and edit data.

The database is housed on a server with `Windows Server 2008 R2 (standard edition)`. Right now I have the application running on five different computers, and users are authenticated through active directory.

One complaint reported to me was that sometimes when different data is entered and submitted, the same data do not appear in the listing that contains the application. I use try catch block to send the errors but errors do not appear in the application; but the data simply disappear.

The id of the table records is an integer auto-increment. As I have to tell them the registration number that was entered I use the following piece of code:

```
try{
    ConectionDataContext db = new ConectionDataContext();
    Table_Registers tr = new Table_Registers();
    tr.Name=textbox1.text;
    tr.sector=textbox2.text;
    db.Table_Registers.InsertOnSubmit(tr);
    db.SubmitChanges();
    int numberRegister=tr.NumberRegister;
    MessageBox.Show(tr.ToString());
}
catch{Exception e}
```

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong or if you know of any article on the web that speaks how to insert data from different clients in MSSQL Server databases, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what a database server *DOES*: "insert data simultaneously from different clients".

One thing you can do is to consider "transactions":

- http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions

Another thing you can (and should!) do is to insure as much work as possible is done on the server, by using "stored procedures":

- http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2003/stored-procedures-basics/

You should also check the SQL Server error logs, especially for potential deadlocks.  You can see these in your SSMS GUI, or in the "logs" directory under your SQL Server installation.

But the *FIRST* thing you need to do is to determine exactly what's going on.  Since you've only got MSSQL Express (which is *not* a good choice for production use!), perhaps the easiest approach is to create a "log" table: insert an entry in your "log" every time you insert a row in the real table, and see if stuff is "missing" (i.e. you have more entires in the log table than the data table).

Comment: Thank you I will follow your advice